# Passing argument 1 of 'setQuantity:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UILabel that I need to get the value from as an integer so I can save it to my Core Data object but I keep getting this error and failure at this point.

```
PurchaseOrderItem *newPOItem = (PurchaseOrderItem*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PurchaseOrderItem" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            int qty = [qtyTextField.text integerValue];
            [newPOItem setProductName:productName.text];
            [newPOItem setDescription:productDescription.text];
            [newPOItem setPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: retailPrice.text]];
            [newPOItem setQuantity:qty];
            [newPOItem setPurchaseorder:newEntity];                                         

            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                // Handle the error.
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }
```

EDIT:
Here is my final solution - seems totally ridiculous but it works:

```
NSDecimalNumber *price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [retailPrice.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""]];
NSNumber *qty = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [qtyTextField.text integerValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *itemSubTotal =[price decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[qty decimalValue]]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the quantity attribute of `PurchaseOrderItem` is declarated as `NSNumber` not `NSInteger`.  If that's the case you'll need to do something similar to the following:

```
[newPOItem setQuantity: [NSNumber numberWithInt: qty]];
```

Comment: that was it, man learning all of the different ways to work with strings and numbers is confusing in objective-c - thank you!

Comment: now I have a NSDecimalNumber and a NSNumber and I need to multiply those 2 - thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NSDecimalNumber.  Is there a reason you're using that instead of NSNumber with floats?  If you were using NSNumbers you could just do that following:

NSNumber result = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [a floatValue] * [b floatValue]];